# Is there any continuous function s.t. $\int_0^1xf(x)dx=1$ and $\int_0^1x^nf(x)dx=0$ for all n=0, 2, 3......

Tags: real-analysis

According to Stone-Weierstrass theorem, there is no nonzero $f \in C([0, 1])$, s.t. $\int_0^1x^nf(x)dx=0$ for all $n\ge0$.
Then what if change the condition to $\int_0^1xf(x)dx=1$ and $\int_0^1x^nf(x)dx=0$ for all n=0, 2, 3......, would such $f \in C([0, 1])$ exist?

Comment: I feel a bit stupid but I am really not seeing how your "changed" condition is any different, except for also including $n=0$

Comment: @Lorago So sorry, edited the quesiton

Comment: This may be helpful: Use the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process to construct "orthogonal" polynomials in $L_2(0,1)$: $P_1(x)=1$, $P_2(x)=2-2x$, etc. See what your condition means in terms of this polynomials...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0 = \int_{0}^{1}x^{n}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}x^{n-2}(x²f(x))dx$ for all $n≥ 2$

Then $\int_{0}^{1}x^{m}(x²f(x)) dx = 0$ for all $m≥0$.

Thus $x²f(x) \equiv 0 \implies f = 0$